# Parsing a range of urls using Urllib2 or Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get data from a site that has the following form: "http://www.mysite.here?pageNo=2"

How do I get the html data from a consecutive range of pages using Urllib2 and/or BeautifulSoup? This code returns the html only for the first page.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for x in range(1,450):
        numb = str(x)
        url = "http://www.mysite.here?pageNo="+numb
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

Print soup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each iteration you create new variable with name `soup`.
You need to create storage for all pages - `list` with `pages`. And append to it on each iteration.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


pages = []
for x in range(1, 450):
    numb = str(x)
    url = "http://www.mysite.here?pageNo=" + numb
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    pages.append(BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser"))

print pages
```

Comment: Hmm...I'd always write the other code inside that `for`  loop if I want to do the same thing with all *`soup`* objects :P

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array `soup = []` and add to it with `soup.append(soup)`.

If you want just one soup object, you need to add the contents at each step, for instance for the body's

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><body></body></body>") # initialize soup
for x in range(1,450):
    numb = str(x)
    url = "http://www.mysite.here?pageNo="+numb
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    tmpsoup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    for element in tmpsoup.body:
      soup.body.append(element)
```